# Prove f(A\G)=B\f(G) implies f(x) is bijective

Tags: analysis, functions, proof-writing

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function. Show that 
$f$ is bijective $\Longleftrightarrow f(A\backslash B)=B\backslash f(G) $,
where $G$ is a subset of A.

I can prove that $f$ is bijective implies $f(A\backslash B)=B\backslash f(G)$ but not the converse. I know that in order to show bijection, we have to demonstrate injection by showing that if $f(a)=f(a')$ then $a=a'$ and surjection by showing that $\forall b\in B, \exists a $ such that $f(a)=b$, but I'm not sure how to obtain these results from the equality. Any ideas?

Comment: Title and the problem are different.

Comment: to clarify: I wrote out the full problem in the question, but the title is the part of the problem I'm having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll prove the result in the title, namely

> If $f[A\setminus G]=B\setminus f[G]$ for all $G\subset A$, then $f$ is bijective.

Firstly, $f$ is surjective, as letting $G=\emptyset$ tells us that
$$f[A\setminus \emptyset] = f[A]=B\setminus f[\emptyset]=B\setminus \emptyset=B.$$

Secondly, $f$ is injective, as given any $a\in A$, letting $G=\{a\}$ tells us that
$$f[A\setminus \{a\}] = B\setminus \{f(a)\},$$
meaning that there cannot be a $a'\in A\setminus \{a\}$ with $f(a)=f(a')$ since $f(a')\in B\setminus \{f(a)\}=f[A\setminus\{a\}]$.

The other variants of the question, namely

> Variant 1: if $f[A\setminus G]=B\setminus f[G]$ for fixed $G\subset A$, then $f$ bijective.
>
> Variant 2: if $f[A\setminus B]=B\setminus f[G]$ for either all or fixed $G\subset A$, then $f$ is bijective.

Are either false (for first, if $G=\emptyset$ then we'll know that $f$ is surjective, but there is no reason for it to also be injective as every surjective map would satisfy $f[A\setminus \emptyset] = B\setminus f[\emptyset]=B$) or doesn't make sense (choose $B$ to be disjoint from $A$, so $f[A\setminus B]=f[A]$ and then choose $G=A$, so $f[A]=B\setminus f[A]$, which is non-sensical unless $A=\emptyset=B$).

Comment: Two questions:
1. Are you allowed to let G=∅ ? Don't we have to show that surjection holds for all possible G?

2. I don't understand why if G={a}, then f(G)={f(a)}. Shouldn't it be f(G)=f({a})?

Comment: I'm assuming the intended question is "If $f[A\setminus G]=B\setminus f[G]$ for all $G\subset A$, then $f$ is bijective", so if this is the actual original question, then: 1) Yes, 2) No, and 3) We're considering the image of $A\setminus G$, not $G$

Comment: Yes, that is the intended question. And I understand now, thank you!